# How does Iterator::all work?

Tags: rust

I do not understand `iter().all`. This code from the docs works:

```
let d = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8];
assert!(a.iter().all(|x| *x > 0));
```

Why does the one below not work?

```
for x in d.iter().all(|x| *x > 2) {
   println!("{} is bigger than 2", x);
}
```

Comment: If you're asking why code doesn't work, it is good to be specific about what doesn't work. In this case, that would mean including the compiler error.

Comment: @huon: or the expect behavior if it does compile but the result is not expected...

Answer (score 5):

`all` tests that the given predicate holds true for all elements. It returns `false` as soon as it finds an element that does not match the predicate, or `true` if all elements match. It is not used to iterate over matching elements. You should probably use `filter` for that. See [the `Iterator::all` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all).